# Golang скопировать файлы между windows ПК

Tags: golang, авторские-права

Есть ПК1 и ПК2 под управлением Windows.
Покажите пожалуйста просто способ скопировать файлы по сети с ПК1 на ПК2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Наверное самый простой вариант

ПК1 https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#example_FileServer

ПК2 https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#example_Get

На ПК2 вместо `ioutil.ReadAll(...` https://golang.org/pkg/io/#example_Copy в новый открытый файл.

Удачи